# Noise when I don't speak

Tags: zoom-h4n, quicktime

I connect Zoom h4n Pro to my Mac via USB as audio interface. I use QuickTime Player to record videos and iMovie to edit videos.

I just recorded a video and am editing it in iMovie (below the image). I realised that with my wireless Apple AirPods I could hear a noise even for the part where I didn't speak; it is also noticeable in the image, the track is not totally empty when I didn't speak.

But with a wired headset, the noise is not noticable.

So my questions are:

1. is it possible to set up QuickTime Player or h4n to avoid this noise while recording videos?
2. is it possible to remove this noise from the recorded videos in QuickTimer Player or iMovie or other software?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is a noise gate. There are several (even free) VST's out there that could achieve the result you are looking for. You could either record your audio into any DAW running such a VST, or apply it to previously recorded audio. Here's an article with more explanation and some recommendations for VST's: https://integraudio.com/10-best-noise-gate-plugins-vst-au-aax/